# Stop counter min value at 0 when using Firstore Fieldvalue increment function

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

Is there way I can stop my number type field value to go negative (minimum 0) when using Firstore Fieldvalue increment and not using transactions?

```
this.afs.doc('path').update({count: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(11)});
```

If the field count has value 0, it will go to -1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A transaction is actually the right way to go here, since you can check the bounds of the value.  `FieldValue.increment()` can't do that.

However, if you want to update to simply fail when provided with invalid values, you can use [Firestore security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) to [validate the field value](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#data_validation).  These rules only work when directly accessed by web and mobile clients.  They don't apply to backend code.

Comment: Thanks Doug. I can user security rules and validate the fields but when the data update happens from cloud functions by admin, rules won't stop it. So I have to use transaction there.

Comment: Yes, you will need a transaction.